# Group similar words/sentences in pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

I tried using the code :

```
Counter(" ".join(df["text"]).split()).most_common(100)
```

TO get the most common words used but what I wanted was count of common words in sentences. 
Eg:

```
1. A123 B234 C345 test data.
2. A123 B234 C345 D555 test data.
3. A123 B234 test data.
4. A123 B234 C345 more data.
```

I wanted the count of :

```
 A123 B234 data- 4
 A123 B234 test data - 3
 A123 B234 C345 test data- 3
```

I'm looking for group of words which are common and have a high count. How can I get this in pandas/python

Example sentences:

```
Money transferred from xyz@abc.com to account no.123
Money transferred from xyz@abc.net to account no.abc
Money failed transferring from xyz@abc. to account no.cde
Money transferred from example@yyy.com to account no.www
Money failed transferring from xyz@abc.com to account no.ttt
```

Comment: I don't understand your desired data set - can you elaborate?

Comment: @MaxU The desired dataset is a a group of words which are matching in every sentence along with the count.

Comment: @jason - how many rows have dataframe? How many unique words?

Comment: @jezrael I'm looking at sorting the values in a descending order of splittig words in a sentence and clustering them together with a count. Something on those line. Like in my example.

Comment: @jason - I ask because if many rows or many unique words not sure if my solution should be fast... Please check it.

Comment: @jezrael It's ok if it takes time. I'll check it out! Thank You for sharing the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Use groupby with multiple columns as input followed by size method

```
df.groupby(['col1','col2','col3']).size().sort_values()
```

Comment: Hi vumaasha. Please explain

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution:

```
df = df['col'].str.get_dummies(' ')
print (df)
   A123  B234  C345  D555  data  more  test
0     1     1     1     0     1     0     1
1     1     1     1     1     1     0     1
2     1     1     0     0     1     0     1
3     1     1     1     0     1     1     0
```

Alternative:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
df = pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(df['col'].str.split()),
                  columns=mlb.classes_, 
                  index=df.index)
print (df)
   A123  B234  C345  D555  data  more  test
0     1     1     1     0     1     0     1
1     1     1     1     1     1     0     1
2     1     1     0     0     1     0     1
3     1     1     1     0     1     1     0
```

---

Get all combination from `min_length` to `max` of all combinations of columns (`words`):

```
from  itertools import combinations
a = df.columns
min_length = 3
comb = [j for i in range(len(a), min_length -1, -1) for j in combinations(a,i)]
```

In list comprehension count values:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([(', '.join(x), df.loc[:, x].all(axis=1).sum(), len(x)) for x in comb], 
                    columns=['words','count','len'])

TOP = 2
TOP_count = sorted(df1['count'].unique())[-TOP:]
df1 = df1[df1['count'].isin(TOP_count)].sort_values(['count', 'len'], ascending=False)
print (df1)
                     words  count  len
66        A123, B234, data      4    3
30  A123, B234, C345, data      3    4
37  A123, B234, data, test      3    4
64        A123, B234, C345      3    3
68        A123, B234, test      3    3
70        A123, C345, data      3    3
77        A123, data, test      3    3
80        B234, C345, data      3    3
87        B234, data, test      3    3
```

EDIT:

Pure python solution:

```
from  itertools import combinations, takewhile
from collections import Counter

min_length = 3
d = Counter()
for a in df['col'].str.split():
    for i in range(len(a), min_length -1, -1):
        for j in combinations(a,i):
            d[j] +=1
#print (d)

#https://stackoverflow.com/a/26831143
def get_items_upto_count(dct, n):
  data = dct.most_common()
  val = data[n-1][1] #get the value of n-1th item
  #Now collect all items whose value is greater than or equal to `val`.
  return list(takewhile(lambda x: x[1] >= val, data))

L = get_items_upto_count(d, 2)

s = pd.DataFrame(L, columns=['val','count'])
print (s)
                        val  count
0        (A123, B234, data)      4
1  (A123, B234, C345, data)      3
2  (A123, B234, test, data)      3
3        (A123, B234, C345)      3
4        (A123, B234, test)      3
5        (A123, C345, data)      3
6        (A123, test, data)      3
7        (B234, C345, data)      3
8        (B234, test, data)      3
```

Comment: Hi Jezreal! I've added sample sentences on top. PLease take a look :)

Comment: @jason - please check chat.