# Getting the average from a dataframe consisting of pandas timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timedelta

I have two panda series, `closedDate` and `createdDate`, thats elements are pandas timestamps, `class 'pandas._libs.tslib.Timestampclass 'pandas._libs.tslib.Timestamp`.

I have subtracted those two panda series to make  a list, `age`, of pandas timedelta.

```
closedDate = data.iloc[:,1]
createdDate = data.iloc[:,2]
age = [x-y for x,y in zip(closedDate, createdDate)]
```

Now, I want to get the average of `age` but with my line of code I get an error.

In: `average_age = functools.reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, age) / len(age)`

Out: `OverflowError: int too big to convert`

How can I fix this??

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can and should aim to use vectorised functions for this task.

In this example, you can subtract one `pd.Series` from another. You can then use the [`mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timedeltas.html#reductions) method to calculate the average.

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'createdDate': [pd.Timestamp('2018-01-01'),
                                     pd.Timestamp('2018-05-01')],
                     'closedDate': [pd.Timestamp('2018-02-01'),
                                    pd.Timestamp('2018-07-01')]})

closedDate = data['closedDate']
createdDate = data['createdDate']

ages = closedDate - createdDate

print(ages)

# 0   31 days
# 1   61 days
# dtype: timedelta64[ns]

res = ages.mean()

print(res)

# 46 days 00:00:00
```

There are 2 main reasons why using vectorised functions are better in this case:

1. Underlying `pd.Timestamp` are numeric arrays ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49758140/9209546)).
2. `zip` on arrays underperforms versus `zip` on lists ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50399219/9209546)).

Answer (score 0):

*You should do this with series like jpp suggested, but barring that, heres how you could do it with the list you provided.*

```
average_age = sum(age, timedelta()) / len(age)
```