# Pandas - pd.merge, add a check to make sure column doesn't exist?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes, one main one that I work with and an auxiliary one that I want to bring info in from.

`df1` (main) contains a Reporter column with various name strings.

`df2` (additional information) contains the reporter name and their location.

I want the location column added as a new column in `df1`.

I can do the following as a one off with:

```
df1 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='Reporter', how='left')
```

**and it works.**

My problem is I run a frequently updating script (checking for new rows and checking for updates on old rows) and running this line of code repeatedly adds multiple columns for each execution.

- The trouble with just checking if the column exists is that a new row (that contains a new reporter name) may have been added to the df that I DO want to know/update the location of.
- Am I going about this the right way? Or should I do some sort of dict lookup and conditionally map the location each time? How can I do that in pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a single series, I often prefer to map a series rather than `merge` or `join` (both also valid options, if used correctly).

Note I assume you have already applied `str` conversion to all columns as appropriate.

```
s = df2.set_index('Reporter')['Reporter Location']

df['Reporter Location'] = df['Reporter'].map(s)
```

In general, there is no need for converting your series to `dict` or for using `zip` on `pd.Series` objects. Using `zip` with `numpy` arrays [can be inefficient](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50399219/9209546).

Answer (score 2):

The problem with `pd.merge` is it always adds suffixes to the result.

**Don't use it.**

Use the equivalent `DataFrame.join` or `DataFrame.merge` on the one you're doing the LEFT JOIN on.

```
df1 = df1.join(df2, on='Reporter', how='left')
```

Or,

```
df1 = df1.merge(df2, on='Reporter', how='left')
```

The common column is only retained once in the result. Other, identical columns between the two (if you have them) are duplicated (with suffixes), however.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the info coldspeed but I went with the second option, mapping the dict.

```
reporter_dict = dict(zip(df2['Reporter'].astype(str),df2['Reporter Location']))
df['Reporter Location'] = df['Reporter'].astype(str).map(reporter_dict)
```