# Combine elements from two arrays by pairs

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

So I want to concatenate two arrays but by pairs. The input is as follows:

```
a = array([1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1])
b = array([0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0])
```

And the output should be as follows:

```
out_put = 
[[1, 0],
[1, 0],
[0, 1],
[1, 0],
[0, 1],
[0, 1],
[0, 1],
[0, 1],
[0, 1],
[0, 1],
[0, 1],
[0, 1],
[0, 1],
[0, 1],
[1, 0]]
```

I managed to get such result by iterating over the two arrays

```
out_put = [[a[i],b[i]] for i in range(len(a)]
```

but I wonder if there any faster way .

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For a vectorised solution, you can stack and transpose:

```
a = np.array([1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1])
b = np.array([0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0])

c = np.vstack((a, b)).T
# or, c = np.dstack((a, b))[0]

array([[1, 0],
       [1, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [1, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 1],
       [1, 0]])
```

Comment: Or just `np.dstack((a, b))`, though it's only a wrapper around concatenate

Comment: @BradSolomon, Thanks, think you'll also need to index `[0]` with that solution.

Comment: @BradSolomon `column_stack` is `dstack` without adding the additional dimension for 2 1D arrays

Answer (score 5):

Using [**`np.column_stack`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html)

> Stack 1-D arrays as columns into a 2-D array.

```
np.column_stack((a, b))

array([[1, 0],  
       [1, 0],  
       [0, 1],  
       [1, 0],  
       [0, 1],  
       [0, 1],  
       [0, 1],  
       [0, 1],  
       [0, 1],  
       [0, 1],  
       [0, 1],  
       [0, 1],  
       [0, 1],  
       [0, 1],  
       [1, 0]])
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function to combine any two iterables like this.  It will continue until it reaches the end of the shorter iterable

```
list(zip(a, b))
# [(1, 0), (1, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1), (1, 0)]
```

Comment: Note: `zip` + NumPy arrays are actually inefficient: see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50399219/9209546).