# Is it possible to combine (add) values of a vector according to integer value of another vector

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, grouping

I'm trying to add float values of a vector according to integer values from another vector.

for instance if I have:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,07.3,0.8,0.9,1.,1.2,1.4])
b = np.array([0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,2]).astype(int)
```

I would like to add the 5 first value of the a vector together (because the 5 first values of b are 0), the 3 next values together (because the 3 next values of b are 1) and so on.
So At the end I woudl expect to have

```
c = function(a,b)
c = [0.1+0.2+0.3+0.4+0.5,  0.6+7.3+0.8, 0.9+1.+1.2+1.4]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Approach #1 :** We can make use of [`np.bincount`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html) with `b` as the bins and `a` as weights array -

```
In [203]: np.bincount(b,a)
Out[203]: array([1.5, 8.7, 4.5])
```

**Approach #2 :** Another leveraging `matrix-multiplication` -

```
In [210]: (b == np.arange(b.max()+1)[:,None]).dot(a)
Out[210]: array([1.5, 8.7, 4.5])
```

Comment: Where do you pull these things from? `bincount`? Marvelous! The matrix multiplication one would be a bad idea for large arrays though. But `bincount` is an order of magnitude faster than my solution.

Comment: Yes that's great. In addition, this is really fast! Thks

Answer (score 4):

For a pure numpy solution, you can check the `np.diff()` of `b`, which will give you a new array of zeros everywhere except wherever the values change. However, this needs one small tweak as `np.diff()` reduces the size of your array by one element, so your indices will be off by one. There actually is current development in numpy to make this better (giving new arguments to pad the output back to original size; see the issue here: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/8132)

With that said...here's something that should be instructive:

```
In [100]: a
Out[100]: array([0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 7.3, 0.8, 0.9, 1. , 1.2, 1.4])

In [101]: b
Out[101]: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2])

In [102]: np.diff(b) # note it is one element shorter than b
Out[102]: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0])

In [103]: np.flatnonzero(np.diff(b))
Out[103]: array([4, 7]) 

In [104]: np.flatnonzero(np.diff(b)) + 1
Out[104]: array([5, 8])

In [105]: np.insert(np.flatnonzero(np.diff(b)) + 1, 0, 0)
Out[105]: array([0, 5, 8]) # these are the indices of the start of each group

In [106]: indices = _

In [107]: np.add.reduceat(a, indices)
Out[107]: array([1.5, 8.7, 4.5])

In [108]: def sumatchanges(a, b):
     ...:     indices = np.insert(np.flatnonzero(np.diff(b)) + 1, 0, 0)
     ...:     return np.add.reduceat(a, indices)
     ...:

In [109]: sumatchanges(a, b)
Out[109]: array([1.5, 8.7, 4.5])
```

I would definitely prefer using Pandas `groupby` as jpp's answer used in most settings, as this is ugly. Hopefully with those changes to numpy, this could be a bit nicer looking and more natural in the future.

---

Note that this answer is equivalent to the `itertools.groupby` answer that Maarten gave (in output). Specifically, that is that the groups are assumed to be sequential. I.e., this

```
b = np.array([0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,2]).astype(int)
```

would produce the same output as with

```
b = np.array([0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0]).astype(int)
```

The number is irrelevant, so long as it changes. However for the other solution Maarten gave, and the pandas solution by jpp, those will sum all the things with the same label, regardless of location. OP is not clear on which you prefer.

---

#### Timing:

Here I'll create a random array for summing and a random array of increasing values with 100k entries each, and test both functions time:

```
In [115]: import timeit
In [116]: import pandas as pd

In [117]: def sumatchangespd(a, b):
     ...:     return pd.Series(a).groupby(b).sum().values
     ...:

In [125]: l = 100_000

In [126]: a = np.random.rand(l)

In [127]: b = np.cumsum(np.random.randint(2, size=l))

In [128]: sumatchanges(a, b)
Out[128]:
array([2.83528234e-01, 6.66182064e-01, 9.32624292e-01, ...,
       2.98379765e-01, 1.97586484e+00, 8.65103445e-04])

In [129]: %timeit sumatchanges(a, b)
1.91 ms ± 47.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [130]: %timeit sumatchangespd(a, b)
6.33 ms ± 267 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Also just to make sure these are equivalent:

```
In [139]: all(np.isclose(sumatchanges(a, b), sumatchangespd(a, b)))
Out[139]: True
```

So the numpy version is faster (not too surprising). Again, these functions could do slightly different things though, depending on your input:

```
In [120]: b  # numpy solution grabs each chunk as a separate piece
Out[120]: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2])

In [121]: b[-4:] = 0

In [122]: b   # pandas will sum the vals in a that have same vals in b
Out[122]: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0])

In [123]: sumatchanges(a, b)
Out[123]: array([1.5, 8.7, 4.5])

In [124]: sumatchangespd(a, b)
Out[124]: array([6. , 8.7])
```

---

Divakar's main solution is brilliant and the best out of all of the above speed-wise:

```
In [144]: def sumatchangesbc(a, b):
     ...:     return np.bincount(b,a)
     ...:

In [145]: %timeit sumatchangesbc(a, b)
175 µs ± 1.16 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Order of magnitude faster than my numpy solution.

Comment: Great answer. Is this actually more efficient than Pandas? I expect it should be as it doesn't have the overhead with `pd.Series` objects.

Comment: I was going to time it and see, I'm curious too. `np.insert()` is not a cheap operation though.

Comment: @jpp Added the timings---numpy is faster. I actually find myself doing this a lot (detecting state changes via `df['col'].diff()` or `np.diff()`). I like pandas better for it currently because it keeps the same length and you can specify the padding value and such, but since numpy will have it soon, I suppose I'll be fine with either!

Comment: Can you try on a larger array (e.g. 100,000 random values)? When timings are in microseconds, I feel they get distorted by fixed costs. (And Pandas certainly has more fixed costs.)

Comment: @jpp agreed and fair point, edited with some new arrays. About 3.5x speedup, which seems more reasonable.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Pandas, which is built on NumPy:

```
import pandas as pd

c = pd.Series(a).groupby(b).sum().values

# array([ 1.5,  8.7,  4.5])
```

Or a more verbose alternative:

```
c = pd.DataFrame({'a': a, 'b': b})\
      .groupby('b')['a'].sum().values
```

Comment: no need to make a `DataFrame`: `pd.Series(a).groupby(b).sum().values` works too

Answer (score 3):

With numpy only

```
c = [sum(a[b==i]) for i in sorted(set(b))]
```

note: as `@jpp` pointed out, it's probably better to write `np.unique` instead of `sorted(set(b))`

Comment: If `b = np.array([2,2,0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,2]).astype(int)` then output will be wrong right ?

Comment: @RahulKP: why? what would be the right one? his example has consecutive, ordered values. he does not specific what should happen otherwise

Comment: He specified values should be the together. In your case, you are not considering the consecutive values.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50399219/9209546) for why you should not use built-ins like `sum` with NumPy arrays.

Answer (score 2):

a native python solution using `itertools.groupby`

```
from itertools import groupby

groups = (group for key, group in groupby(zip(a, b), key=lambda x: x[1]))
totals = [sum(a for a, b in group) for group in groups]
```

> ```
> [1.5, 8.7, 4.5]
> ```

a numpy alternative, similar to @blue_note's solution, but using the power of numpy instead of native python

```
[(a * (b == group)).sum() for group in np.unique(b)]
```

This only works if `b = np.array([2,2,0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,2])` does not contain 2 distinctive groups `2`

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50399219/9209546) for why you should not use built-ins like `sum` / `zip` with NumPy arrays.

Comment: The numpy alternative uses `numpy.array.sum`, not the built-in

Comment: Yep, that's true, thought it now has O(*m* * *n*) complexity, where *m* is number of ids and *n* is number of rows of values. That said, I hope my comment encourages people to use the NumPy alternative, that was certainly the intention.